# sns matplotlib output slicing the saved image

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to save sns matplotlib output as jpg file and reopen it with cv2.

but i am facing distinct data loss, would someone help me to resolve, i tried in several savefig options and documentations.

sample code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cv2
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
by_c = None

fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
g = sns.FacetGrid(pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10)*150, columns=['col']), col=None,  row=None, height=3.5, aspect=1)
g.map_dataframe(sns.histplot, x='col')
plt.title('col'+' - '+str(by_c)+'-', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Value')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.savefig('temp.png')
plt.show()
```

Out:

[image]

Saved picture example of 'temp.png'

[image: Saved Picture of temp.png]
out:

reopening image

```
im = cv2.imread('temp.png')
plt.imshow(im)
```

Out1:
Image title and lables sliced bit, i am not sure how else i can save it. Would someone please help to resolve it

[image]

Comment: to rule out problems in cv2: can you post temp.png in the question as well?

Comment: Actually, temp.png is also same @LudvigH, i tried to open it, opencv is simply opening what is saved :-|

Comment: ok. super. I think you can remove cv2 from the question altogether then...

Comment: @LudvigH, Thanks for support , link really shown exact ans, seems i might not checked properly

Answer (score 1):

To set the quality of the image use the `dpi`, and also specify the `bbox_inches` for a full layout. If not, it will consider the nearest view of the image

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cv2
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
by_c = None

fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
g = sns.FacetGrid(pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10)*150, columns=['col']), col=None,  row=None, height=3.5, aspect=1)
g.map_dataframe(sns.histplot, x='col')
plt.title('col'+' - '+str(by_c)+'-', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Value')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.savefig('temp.png',dpi=300, bbox_inches = "tight")
#plt.savefig('temp.png')
plt.show()

im = cv2.imread('temp.png')
plt.imshow(im)
```

Resultant Image:

[image: resultant image]

Comment: this sure should fix the issue. but we should try to flag duplicates rather than answering them. 

also - please tidy code in answers so they are actually good code samples. (e.g. remove unnecessary cv2 dependency

Comment: Thanks for the update. Done as said. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Roxy, it solved the problem :)

Comment: If it resolves, could you accept it as an answer maybe?